# Problem In Route CodeIgniter when access file on public_html

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have problem when route my site.

```
$route['(:any)']        = 'salam/salam/$1';
```

because of this route, i cant access my file on https://example.com/OneSignalSDKWorker.js, please give me a solution. thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem okay to redirect all of the queries to this page.

Anyway if you want to exclude something you can add it before that line with

```
$route['(admin|login|home|sign_up)'] = "$1";
```

That are example urls, but you can add OneSignalSDKWorker.js as well. That would load them and everything else would be redirected to salam/salam